# Updating mysql numeric field knowing only direction

Tags: mysql

I have mysql table like this: `id, [.....], priority`

The priority field is used to sort table as I want. It's based on human intelligence.  I have some values in it:

```
id, priority
1, 1
2, 7
3, 2
4, 4
5, 6
6, 5
7, 3
```

and second (BIGGEST) problem:
For example I want to move the 4th element **up** or **down** depending on priority.

4th element moved UP(left) and DOWN(right)

```
    1, 1         1,1
    2, 7         2,7
    3, 2         3,2
    4, 3         4,5
    5, 6         5,6
    6, 5         6,4
    7, 4         7,3
```

i want to do it with single mysql query, because it's called via ajax and I don't want a lot of queries to be executed on serverside.

Comment: Could you make an example of how exactly your whole table is going to change after a query?

Comment: Please post what you've tried, and how it has not worked. Till then it is just another "give me teh codez" question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$int_prio = (1 - ((int)($_POST['move_up'] == 'TRUE') * 2));
$int_id = (int)$_POST['id'];

mysql_query("
INSERT INTO table_name (id, priority)
SELECT h2.id, 
    (h2.priority + ({$int_prio} * (1 - (2 * (h.id != h2.id))))) AS priority
FROM (  SELECT id, priority
        FROM table_name
        WHERE id = {$int_id}
        HAVING priority BETWEEN 2 AND ( SELECT MAX(priority)
                                        FROM priority
                                        GROUP BY '1') - 1) AS h
INNER JOIN priority AS h2
ON h.priority IN (h2.priority, h2.priority + {$int_prio})
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE priority = VALUES(priority)
");
```

Basicly change the $_POST (preferable to more safier) and the `table_name`.

I've added validation so that it doesn't try to change highest and lowest priority aswell.

Sorry if you find above query confusing, but that's a way to update it all in a single query with added validation.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't changing the priority up or down just swap the priorities? There's a nice solution here: [Swap values in 2 rows SQL](http://www.microshell.com/database/sql/swap-values-in-2-rows-sql/). This swaps the priorities of record 1 and 4

```
UPDATE yourtable AS t1
JOIN yourtable AS t2 ON 
       (t1.id = 1 AND t2.id = 4)
    OR (t1.id = 4 AND t2.id = 1)
SET
    t1.priority = t2.priority,
    t2.priority = t1.priority
```

Actually, if your priorities are unique, you can swap without using the id, and just use the priority. This swaps priority 4 and 5:

```
UPDATE yourtable AS t1
JOIN yourtable AS t2 ON 
       (t1.priority = 4 AND t2.priority = 5)
    OR (t1.priority = 5 AND t2.priority = 4)
SET
    t1.priority = t2.priority,
    t2.priority = t1.priority
```

Comment: it's nice way to solve problem. but i have only ID (that i want to swap) and direction (up or down)... so i don't know ID of target, neither Priority and so on... Thanks anyway )

Answer (score 0):

If you need to move 4 down:

```
UPDATE your_table AS t1 JOIN your_table AS t2 ON (t1.id = 4 AND t2.priority = t1.priority + 1) SET t1.priority = t2.priority, t2.priority = t1.priority
```

Or, say, if you need to move 2 up:

```
UPDATE your_table AS t1 JOIN your_table AS t2 ON (t1.id = 2 AND t2.priority = t1.priority - 1) SET t1.priority = t2.priority, t2.priority = t1.priority
```

Comment: @Ika specifically asked for a single-statement solution though.

Comment: It is a single-statement solution. I just gave two use cases.